# Why does @StackStatus follow Ryan Seacrest?

Tags: discussion, fun, twitter

I couldn't help but notice that the [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/) twitter account follows [@RyanSeacrest](https://twitter.com/RyanSeacrest/).

[image]

@StackStatus provides status updates for the Stack Exchange network along with [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/), so there doesn't seem to be any obvious reason for the account to follow Ryan Seacrest. Is there some joke here that I'm missing?

Can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: Obviously Ryan Seacrest is actually a unicorn in disguise.

Comment: An SE employee who has control over that account probably forgot to switch over to their personal account while browsing Twitter.

Comment: Ryan Seacrest is where @StackStatus gets its information from.

Comment: It's a very [low key inside joke.](https://www.google.com/search?q=ryan%20seacrest%20site%3Astackexchange.com)

Comment: I have hunch it is secret signal "Canary Resets". (Though [recreants say] [Cesareans try] [a scary resent]).

Comment: Oh https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/492770826522230784

Comment: Note: It looks like this is no longer true, as the account no longer follows anyone :P

Answer (score 54):

The [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has been gaining sentience, ever since it was introduced.

Thankfully, with this level of intelligence, we don't have much to fear.

Comment: yet. #yolo

Comment: If that's what @Community is choosing to do with it's sentience, we might need to terminate.

Comment: I, For One, Welcome Our New Community Overlord.

Comment: I'm just waiting for @Community to answer this question .

Comment: @SantaClaus - when you award it the bounty, where would the rep go?

Comment: @Oded I have no idea, which is why I want to find out.

Comment: @Oded Maybe the rep would go to Ryan Seacrest?

Comment: :O. @Community bypassed the comment character limit! And he did it without any invisible special characters! He's all-powerful! Everybody panic! *runs in circles screaming*

Comment: @Community Still waiting for that answer...

Comment: @Community You better [watch out](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/495759307346952192)

Comment: I am part of the @Community

Comment: @Community How did you do that? I didn't know robots could comment.