# Why are some comments listed in Community's network profile?

Tags: support, comments, community-user

The [network profile of Community user](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) lists a number of comments: some templated (invalid links, etc; explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159113/259867)), some posted by developers as a joke (explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161593/259867)).

However, most of its recent comments are of a different kind....

> - After following above steps, ap-hotspot was not working
> - 200-250° F for 2-3 hours will kill any parasites... and NO, you can't make it 'go faster' by increasing the temperature.
> - Merci ! Au moins j'ai compris que le passé simple c'est déjà passer et n'as pas de conséquences dans le présent et le passé composé si.

Following the links shows the comments were left by deleted users, the name Community is not present on actual pages.

But there are certainly many more comments left by deleted users than these. So it seems there is something special about these comments. What is it?

And by the way: [yesterday's comment by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237001/why-does-stackstatus-follow-ryan-seacrest#comment777117_237002) does not show up in its network profile.

Comment: The only special thing is that they are still around. The community user doesn't actually leave comments, it just takes the responsibility for those comments which would otherwise not have an associated account. For example, after account deletions.

Comment: @Bart  But there are tons of deleted users and their comments. The profile only has a couple dozens for the whole 2014 year.

Comment: Oded explains the reasoning below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes deletion of a user would adversely affect many other users (if the deleted user was one that upvoted many posts, for example).

In such cases, the content created by the user gets re-assigned to the Community user, as part of the cleanup and to ensure that the given rep is accounted for.

A side effect is that comments and posts, on occasion, are seen on the Community user account.

These do get cleared out by a scheduled task, so do get removed eventually.

Comment: Does it also explain [favorited questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175992/what-can-cause-the-community-user-to-have-favorite-questions) then? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - possibly. Though what Tim Stone said is an even more esoteric reason.