# How to activate the Community bot to comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-user, fun

In the answer of [Why does @StackStatus follow Ryan Seacrest?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237002/260800), miracle happens:

[image: image description]

How to activate the [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) to comments?

PS: [wow, this bot is smarter than I thought](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=comments)

Comment: Many comments are "real", and part of a now-abandoned system to detect and fix broken links. The rest are, well, just for fun.

Comment: Why would someone downvote a fun question?

Comment: Fun is less popular these days, I'm afraid. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard those was the days that I had fun with funny people...

Comment: I fear those days are lost... some fun still persist in chat though. :-)

Comment: and now it's getting upvotes again...

Comment: Well, still far less than in the past, but yeah... guess not all is lost after all. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Apply for a job [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-overflow?c=62IeP5BU9xQoV2#jobs).
2. Get access to Stack Overflow live database.
3. Download Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062).
4. Connect to the live database.
5. Run the following query:

   ```
   Insert Into Comments (PostId, Text, UserDisplayName, UserId) Values (268068, 'hello, I took over the world. Surrender!', '', -1)
   ```
6. Rejoice.

Comment: BRO TIP: Use magnets for faster database access acquiring

Comment: @Konamiman how?

Comment: @Ooker All the details are here: http://trollscience.com